# Проблема с кодом игры "Виселица" по книге «Учим Python, делая крутые игры»

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему то выдаёт ошибку line 119
gameIsDone = True
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Помогите пожалуйста решить данную проблему.

````
HANGMAN_PICS = ['''
    +---+
        |
        |
        |
        ===''', '''
    +---+
        |
         |
         |
        ===''', '''
    +---+
    0   |
    |   |
        |
        ===''','''
    +---+
    0   |
   /|   |
        |
        ===''','''
    +---+
    0   |
   /|\  |
        |
        ===''','''
    +---+
    0
   /|\
   /
        ===''', '''
    +---+
    0   |
   /|\  |
   / \  |
        ===''']
words = '''аист акула бабуин баран барсук бобр бык верблюд волк воробей ворон выдра голубь гусь жаба змея
индюк кит кобра коза козел койот корова кошка кролик крыса курица лама ласка лебедь лев лиса лосось лось
лягушка медведь моллюск моль мул муравей мышь норка носорог обезьяна овца окунь олень орел осел панда паук питон
попугай пума семга скунс собака сова тигр тритон тюлень утка форель корек черепаха ятреб ящерица'''.split()

def RandomWord(wordList):
    # Эта функция возвращает случайную строку из переданного списка
    wordIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordList) -1)
    return wordList [wordIndex]

def displayBoard(missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord):
    print(HANGMAN_PICS[len(missedLetters)])
    print()
    
    print('Ошибочные буквы:', end=' ')
    for letter in missedLetters:
        print(letter, end=' ')
    print()
    
    blanks = '_' * len(secretword)
    
    for i in range(len(secretWord)): # Заменяет пропуски отгаданными буквами
        if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
            blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]
            
    for letter in blanks: # Показывает секретное слово с пробелами между буквами
        print(letter, end=' ')
    print()
    
def getGuess(alreadyGuessed):
    # Возвращает букву, введённую игроком. Эта функция проверяет, что игрок ввёл только одну букву и ничего больше.
    while True:
        print('Введите букву.')
        guess = input()
        guess = guess.lower()
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print('Пожалуйста, введите одну букву.')
        elif guess in alreadyGuessed:
            print('Вы уже называли эту букву. Назовите другую.')
        elif guess not in 'абвгдеежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя':
            print('Пожалуйста, введите букву.')
        else:
            return guess
        
def playAgain():
    # Эта функция возвращает значение True, если игрок хочет сыграть заново; в противном случае возвращает False.
    print('Хотите сыграть ещё? (да или нет)?')
    return input().lower().startswith('д')


print('В И С Е Л И Ц А')
missedLetters = ''
correctLetters = ''
secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
gameIsDone = False

while True:
    displayBoard(missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)

    # Позволяет игроку ввести букву.
    guess = getGuess(missedLetters + correctLetters)

    if guess in secretWord:
        correctLetters = correctLetters + guess
        
        # Проверяет, выиграл ли игрок.
        foundAllLetters = True
        for i in range(len(secretWord)):
            if secretWord[i] not in correctLetters:
                foundAllLetters = False
                break
        if foundAllLetters:
            print('ДА! Секретное слово - "' + secretWord + '"! Вы угадали!')
            gameIsDone = True
    else:
        missedLetters = missedLetters + guess
        
        # Проверяет, превысил ли игрок лимит попыток и проиграл
        if len(missedLetters) == len(HANGMAN_PICS) - 1:
            display.Board(missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)
            print('Вы исчерпали все попытки!\nНе угадано букв:' + str(len(missedLetters) + 'и угадано букв:' + str(len(correctLetters)) + '.Было загадано слово"' + secretWord + '".')
            gameIsDone = True
            
    # Запрашивает, хочет ли игрок сыграть заново (только если игра завершена).
    if gameIsDone:
        if playAgain():
            missedLetters = ''
            correctLetters = ''
            gameIsDone = False
            secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
        else:
            break ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Потому что в предыдущей строке у вас не хватает закрывающей скобки

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [Постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию, изложите свои предложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1272119/edit)

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло)

Answer (score 0):

Глава 9 Книги "Учим Python, делая крутые игры", тоже заметил ошибки.

Мой код:

```
def get_random_word(word_dict):
    # Эта функция возварщает случайную строку из переданного словаря списков строк, 
    #  а также ключ.
    # Во - первых, случайным образом выбираем ключ из словаря:
    
    word_key = random.choice(list(words.keys()))
    word_dif = words[word_key]
    word_index = random.choice(word_dif)
    return word_index
```