# Ошибка в игре "Виселица" по книге "Учим Python делая крутые игры"

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр

Ошибка:
line 56
def getRandomWord(wordDict):
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Помогите пожалуйста решить ;)

Вот код:

```
import random
HANGMAN_PICS = ['''
    +---+
        |
        |
        |
        ===''', '''
    +---+
        |
         |
         |
        ===''', '''
    +---+
    0   |
    |   |
        |
        ===''','''
    +---+
    0   |
   /|   |
        |
        ===''','''
    +---+
    0   |
   /|\  |
        |
        ===''','''
    +---+
    0
   /|\
   /
        ===''', '''
    +---+
    0   |
   /|\  |
   / \  |
        ===''','''
    +---+
   [0   |
   /|\  |
   / \  |
        ===''','''
    +---+
   [0]  |
   /|\  |
   / \  |
        ===''']
        
   
    
words = {'Цвета':'красный оранжевый жёлтый зелёный синий голубой фиолетовый белый чёрный коричневый'.split(),
'Фигуры':'квадрат треугольник прямоугольник круг эллипс ромб трапеция параллелограмм пятиугольник шестиугольник восьми угольник'.split(),
'Фрукты':'яблоко апельсин лимон лайм груша мандарин виноград грейпфрут персик банан абрикос манго нектарин'.split(),
'Животные':'аист бабуин баран барсук бык волк зебра кит коза корова кошка кролик крыса лев лиса лось медведь мул мышь норка носорог обезьяна овца олень осел панда пума скунс собака сова тигр тюлень хорек ящерица'.split()

def getRandomWord(wordDict):
    # Эта функция возвращает случайную строку из переданного словаря списков строк, а также ключ.
    # Во-первых, случайным образом выбираем ключ из словаря:
    wordKey = random.choice(list(wordDict.keys()))
    
    # Во-вторых, случайным образом выбираем слово из списка ключей в словаре:
    wordIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordDict[wordKey]) - 1)
    
    return [wordDict[wordKey][wordIndex], wordKey]

def displayBoard(missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord):
    print(HANGMAN_PICS[len(missedLetters)])
    print()
    
    print('Ошибочные буквы:', end=' ')
    for letter in missedLetters:
        print(letter, end=' ')
    print()
    
    blanks = '_' * len(secretWord)
    
    for i in range(len(secretWord)): # Заменяет пропуски отгаданными буквами
        if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
            blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]
            
    for letter in blanks: # Показывает секретное слово с пробелами между буквами
        print(letter, end=' ')
    print()
    
def getGuess(alreadyGuessed):
    # Возвращает букву, введённую игроком. Эта функция проверяет, что игрок ввёл только одну букву и ничего больше.
    while True:
        print('Введите букву.')
        guess = input()
        guess = guess.lower()
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print('Пожалуйста, введите одну букву.')
        elif guess in alreadyGuessed:
            print('Вы уже называли эту букву. Назовите другую.')
        elif guess not in 'абвгдеежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя':
            print('Пожалуйста, введите БУКВУ')
        else:
            return guess
        
def playAgain():
    # Эта функция возвращает значение True, если игрок хочет сыграть заново; в противном случае возвращает False.
    print('Хотите сыграть ещё? (да или нет)')
    return input().lower().startswith('д')


print('В И С Е Л И Ц А')

difficulty = ''
while difficulty not in 'ЛСТ':
    print('Выберите уровень сложности: Л - Легкий, С - Средний, Т - Тяжёлый')
    difficulty = input().upper()
if difficulty == 'С':
    del HANGMAN_PICS[8]
    del HANGMAN_PICS[7]
if difficulty == 'Т':
    del HANGMAN_PICS[8]
    del HANGMAN_PICS[7]
    del HANGMAN_PICS[5]
    del HANGMAN_PICS[3]
    
missedLetters = ''
correctLetters = ''
secretWord, secretSet = getRandomWord(words)
gameIsDone = False
secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
gameIsDone = False

while True:
    displayBoard(missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)

    # Позволяет игроку ввести букву.
    guess = getGuess(missedLetters + correctLetters)

    if guess in secretWord:
        correctLetters = correctLetters + guess
        
        # Проверяет, выиграл ли игрок.
        foundAllLetters = True
        for i in range(len(secretWord)):
            if secretWord[i] not in correctLetters:
                foundAllLetters = False
                break
        if foundAllLetters:
            print('ДА! Секретное слово - "' + secretWord + '"! Вы угадали!')
            gameIsDone = True
    else:
        missedLetters = missedLetters + guess
        
        # Проверяет, превысил ли игрок лимит попыток и проиграл
        if len(missedLetters) == len(HANGMAN_PICS) - 1:
            displayBoard(missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)
            print('Вы исчерпали все попытки!\nНе угадано букв:' + str(len(missedLetters)) + ' и угадано букв:' + str(len(correctLetters)) + '.Было загадано слово"' + secretWord + '".')
            gameIsDone = True
            
        # Запрашивает, хочет ли игрок сыграть заново (только если игра завершена).
        if gameIsDone:
            if playAgain():
                missedLetters = ''
                correctLetters = ''
                gameIsDone = False
                secretWord, secretSet = getRandomWord(words)
                secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
            else:
                break
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с кодом игры "Виселица" по книге «Учим Python, делая крутые игры»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1272117/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%92%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b5-%d0%a3%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bc-python-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%8b)

Comment: Это не дубликат, у меня есть 2 вопроса на одну и ту же тему, но ошибки в коде разные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У словаря `words` нет закрывающей фигурной скобки. Если это исправить, все заработает.